# Import all dataframes created into an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to code some kind of function in order to import all the dataframes created to an excel file. But each variable needs to be in a separate excel file

I have created an example:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2': ['azs','bdq','bzm','bqm','csm','dqs','cm','a','z','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Finding the lines that contain a certain expression
a = df[df['col2'].str.contains("a")]
b = df[df['col2'].str.contains("b")]
c = df[df['col2'].str.contains("c")]

#importing to excel

a.to_excel("a.xlsx")
b.to_excel("b.xlsx")
c.to_excel("c.xlsx")
```

The thing is, I have around 250 variables created in my code so I cant import them to excel manually but I don't know where to continue from here.

```
for __name__ in vars().keys():
  print(__name__)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure I know the issue, but you could change to

```
for key, item in vars().items():
    if isinstance(item, pd.core.frame.DataFrame):
        item.to_excel(f'{key}.xlsx')
        print(f'printed {key} to {key}.xslx')
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out ! When i run this code it shows error : '' name 'pandas' is not defined ''

Comment: try pd.core.frame.DataFrame :) if you've imported pandas as pd

Comment: it shows error module 'pandas.core.frame' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Comment: sorry I capitalized DataFrame wrong, note the f, I'll re-edit the original post to reflect those two changes. Eternally frustrating that f

Comment: thats it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
filter_set = df['col2'].unique()

for val in filter_set:
    df.loc[df['col2'].str.contains(val)].to_excel("{}.xlsx".format(val))
```

Solution that will work with your modified question:

```
import pandas as pd

#Creating dataframe
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'col2': ['azs','bdq','bzm','bqm','csm','dqs','cm','a','z','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# assuming you want to search these substrings/characters in col2
search_str = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for val in search_str:
    df.loc[df['col2'].str.contains(val)].to_excel("{}.xlsx".format(val))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! But this is not a valid method since the data in ''col2'' in my program, are made of sentences and as so, most of them are unique values.

Comment: Got it. But the substrings that you are looking to search must be unique, isnt it? Can you share an example close to your real data?

Comment: " #Finding the lines that contain a certain letter" how are you identifying the 'certain letter'?

Comment: I made and edit on the example. Hope i can explain myself better now.  Not particularly. There might be several unique values that will merge to the same variable

Comment: " #Finding the lines that contain a certain expression" how are you identifying the 'certain expression'?

Comment: in the part contains("a")

Comment: Apologies. I think I am not making myself clear. What I am trying to understand is what is the criteria on which you want to split and create the excel files.

Comment: Apologies. I think I am not making myself clear. What I am trying to understand is what is the criteria on which you want to split and create the excel files. Like in the example you have shared, you are looking to split the data based on the condition that the column 'col2' will have the character 'a' or 'b' or 'c'. What is the list of such characters or expressions you need to look for?